# How to show all products in one page in magento1.7

Tags: magento

I have tried but fails to show .

I am using

```
{{block type="catalog/product_special" template="catalog/product/special.phtml"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to alter your collection like this to list all the products.

```
 $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                        ->getCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

foreach ($collection as $product) {
    echo $product->getName() . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: I am very new to magento . Can you pls tell how to show step by step ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to show related product or all special product in one page.

Try This :

http://www.voodish.co.uk/articles/related-products-on-product-page-in-magento/

Good Luck

Comment: NO no I want to show all products on one page . Is that possible ?